# Rounded corner on UIView not working only in few simulators like iPhone8, iPhone6s, iPhone6s plus, iPhone 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uibezierpath

I have a requirement to get rounded corner on the top left and right of a view. Below is the code for the same.

```
let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.alertView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: size)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.frame = self.alertView.bounds
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        self.alertView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

This is working fine in all the simulators iPhone 8 plus and above. But for the rest of the simulators like iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus etc the code is not working as required. I even tried using multiple types of views but it is not working as per the requirement. I get only rounded corner on the left side but not on the right. Below are the screenshots of the UIView from different simulators

iPhone 11 (working fine)

[image]

iPhone 8 (not working as per requirement)

[image]

I am not getting the issue here. Kindly help!

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: When is created that corner? My guess? You are doing it too soon, before the layout has been made according to the size (cf constraints).

Comment: where are you calling this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569864/swift-setting-calayer-bounds-or-frame-not-working for instance, that's when you should call it.

Comment: @PGDev I'm using the latest iOS 13 version.

Comment: calling it in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: @jawadAli I'm calling this in viewDidLoad. But this is working fine in iPhone 8+ and later.. That is what is confusing me. The iOS version is 13 itself.

Comment: @Guest That's because the layout hasn't been applied yet. Reset it when `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use **`maskedCorners`** and **`cornerRadius`** for that?

```
self.alertView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
self.alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I want rounded corners only on top left and top right. But the code that you have sent will give me rounded corners on all four corners right?

Comment: @Guest No it won't. [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner] mean something here

Comment: This solution is applicable to ios11 onwards. Also, it needed alertView.clipsToBounds = true to work

Comment: Hey the solution worked perfectly fine.. Just the way I wanted. This is a better way of doing it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Add corner Radius in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead of `viewDidLoad()`

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     self.alertView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
     self.alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

Comment: Don’t add duplicate answers.

Comment: While technically a duplicate answer it does provide more detail on where to add the lines which is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width * 0.80, height: 30)
```

or

```
let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.065, height: 30)
```

Numbers can change. It means that the width is up to 80 percent of the phone's screen.

Comment: you gave a constant value to the width. iPhone 11 is widescreen compared to iPhone 8. When you say 30, it does not cause trouble. You can try the above code to make it dynamic. so it becomes the image you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this on every device. please try this one :

```
  let viewSub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200, height: 200))

viewSub.backgroundColor = .red
viewSub.center =  self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(viewSub)

let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = viewSub.frame
rectShape.position = viewSub.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewSub.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [ .topRight , .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

viewSub.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
//Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
viewSub.layer.mask = rectShape
```